# Oracle Trigger WHEN clause troubles

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my Trigger that I am trying to create, however, every time I compile I get success but when I close the window and reopen the Trigger it removes the WHEN clause thus my trigger is executed every time instead of WHEN X.  I am using Oracle 10g express edition.  My question is whether or not this is a properly formatted PL/SQL Trigger or not?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECKQUAN 
  AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.QuanInStock <= New.ReorderQuan)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO reorder (prodnum, requestdatetime, reorderquan)
  VALUES (:OLD.productid ,SYSDATE, :OLD.reorderquan);
END CHECKQUAN;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What tool are you using to view the trigger source?  BTW, I concur with @OldProgrammer - syntax looks good to me.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I am simply viewing it by clicking on the trigger name.  But when I click export the DDL I see it and also in the user_trigger table the WHEN is there.  So for whatever reason it just doesn't show up in the Oracle SQL Developer window.  I am guessing then all is okay. In my panic I didn't think to check the tables or what it printed out in the DDL summary.  But thank you both for checking the syntax.

Comment: From memory I think there was a bug in SQL Developer around this - exporting trigger as DDL lost some stuff - but I may be mis-remembering this.